# What of these CiviCRM features comes 'out of the box'?

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

On the CiviCRM demo -- there are lots of great features / fields etc.  What comes *standard*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd caution that 'standard' is a slippery word. Since CiviCRM is of the 'community' style of open source, there's no 'pro' version with extra features, so Ramesh has the right answer to that question.

On the other hand, even after you put aside the financial hurdles, there's still the complexity hurdles of additional 'features'. So another answer is that you actually get more than the demo, and still for free, as you climb these hills:

1. Understanding how CiviCRM can be configured 'out of the box', beyond
   what you see in the demo (see ramesh's documentation link)
2. Understanding how extensions can be downloaded/enabled and finding
   ones that match your needs.
3. Understanding the open sourceness and
   'plugability' of the code to extend CiviCRM in ways that are
   specific to your organization and no one else has (yet), by writing
   your own extension and or contributing to core.

For someone coming from the WordPress community, you'll find that there are a lot more free but still high-quality extensions and not the same kind of 'market' that Wordpress world is used to.

Answer (score 6):

The demo has the following extensions enabled by default, which are not part of CiviCRM core:

- CiviVolunteer (features under the "Volunteer" menu)
- CiviRules (Administer > CiviRules; this is a rather advanced extension)
- Civisualize (it might be disabled at the moment, it provides fancy graphics)

All these extensions are freely available under the same terms as CiviCRM, and are available for Drupal, WordPress and Joomla. If I recall correctly, they can all be installed using the one-click installer in the Administer > System settings > Extensions screen (if the file permissions allow it).

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to CiviCRM

Yes is the answer

Anything you see in the demo are in-build feature which comes with the core

Indeed it has lots of great features - If you explore further you will find more amazing features

refer: http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/dashboard

documentation: https://civicrm.org/documentation

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Ramesh, are all the installed Extensions on the dmaster demo site installed with a standard build? Or added after?